# Refusal of tier 2 UK visa

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

I applied for tier 2 general dependent ( partner) visa to accompany my husband, who is working in UK. But my visa got refused at the entry clearance level due to the absence of wedding photos whereas I stated that I attached the photos perhaps I forgot to attach it. Now what can I do, whether to reapply for it or appeal over it or to make a administrative review..... Can anyone help me please [image][image]

Comment: **due to the absence of wedding photos ** Can you post a redacted scan of your refusal letter please? That looks like your assessment of the letter, not the wording of that letter itself.

Comment: VTC: this is a better fit on [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/uk-dependent-visa-refusal-can-i-apply-for-review-in-this-situation), and where the linked response covers Tier 2 administrative review rights